# Why does url not working in css while using linear?

Tags: css

```css
.main-header {
  height: 95;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, (10, 132, 255, 0.8), (59, 215, 75, 0.8), url(../logo/car2.jpg));
}
```

I tried lots but it's not working I can't figure out what is the problem with it

Comment: height needs to have `px` -> 95px. need also `rgb()` not `()`

Comment: check well your `)`, they are not good

Comment: Linear gradients don't have an image parameter.

Comment: The format for the gradient is off. The gradient should be closed before the URL is specified. The closing `)` should be before the comma before the `url` as Temani mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```css
.main-header {
  height: 95px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      rgb(10, 132, 255, 0.8),
      rgb(59, 215, 75, 0.8)
    ),
    url("https://picsum.photos/300");
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  hello
</header>
```